# Split the sentence into two parts not cutting off letters included in the last part of the word

Tags: php, regex

```
if (mb_strlen($str,'UTF-8')>=310) { 
    $half=intval(mb_strlen($str,'UTF-8')/2);    
    $partOne=mb_substr($str,0,$half);
    $partTwo=mb_substr($str,mb_strlen($partOne,'UTF-8'));
}
```

But I may be so

```
 echo $partOne;// text.............stri
 echo $partTwo //ng....................
```

this is not true should be

```
echo $partOne;// text.............string
echo $partTwo;//...some text
```

Comment: Where's the sentence? You need to check what character you are cutting on.

Comment: can substitute any

Comment: This might be what you're looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187429/split-strings-in-half-word-aware-with-php

Comment: `$middle = floor(mb_strlen($str,'UTF-8') / 2);

    $before = mb_strripos($str' ',$middle, 'UTF-8');
    $after = mb_strpos($str,' ', $middle + 1,'UTF-8');
    if ($middle - $before < $after - $middle) {
    $middle = $before;
    } else {
       $middle = $after;
  }
$string1 = mb_substr($str,0, $middle);
$string2 = mb_substr($str,$middle + 1);`