# PHP - Split string into 2 equal parts but more words in the second string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function to split a string into 2 equal parts based on the number of words in the string. I am then wrapping the 2 new strings in individual `span`s. In the event that there's an odd number of words in the original string, I would like the 2nd span to contain the 1 additional word.

Currently the additional word is going to the first `span`:

```
$array  = explode( ' ', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' );
$count = count( $array );
$per_part = max( round( $count / 2 ), 1 );
$new_array     = [];

for ( $i = 0; $i < 2; $i++ ) {
    $new_array[] = array_slice( $array, $i * $per_part, $per_part );
}

$first_string = join(' ', $new_array[0]);
$second_string = join(' ', $new_array[1]);

$new_string = '<span>' . $first_string . '</span>' . ' <span>' . $second_string . '</span>';
echo htmlspecialchars($new_string);
```

Current result:

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span> <span>sit amet</span>
```

Desired result:

```
<span>Lorem ipsum</span> <span>dolor sit amet</span>
```

Comment: What is the expected result when you have ANY punctuation in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the number of words per part by rounding down the total count of words divided by 2. This will give you the number of words for the first part. Then, calculate the remaining words which will be added to the second part.

```
$array = explode( ' ', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' );
$count = count( $array );
$per_part = floor( $count / 2 );
$remaining_words = $count - $per_part;

$new_array = [];

$new_array[] = array_slice( $array, 0, $per_part );
$new_array[] = array_slice( $array, $per_part );

$first_string = join(' ', $new_array[0]);
$second_string = join(' ', $new_array[1]);

$new_string = '<span>' . $first_string . '</span>' . ' <span>' . $second_string . '</span>';
echo htmlspecialchars($new_string); //Expected Output: <span>Lorem ipsum</span> <span>dolor sit amet</span>
```

`floor( $count / 2 )` is used to ensures that the first part gets the majority of the words when the total count is odd. The remaining words are then added to the second part. This way, if there's an odd number of words in the original string, the 2nd span will contain the 1 additional word.

Comment: You don't really need `$remaining_words`; `array_slice` will just give you all the words from `$per_part` onwards with no `length` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by calculating how many words each part should contain based on whether the total word count is even or odd, so if it's even, both parts will contain the same number of words, and if it's odd, the first part will contain one additional word. Something like this

```
$array  = explode( ' ', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' );
$count = count( $array );
$per_part = max(ceil($count / 2), 1);
$new_array     = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $new_array[] = array_slice($array, $i * $per_part, $per_part);
}

if ($count % 2 === 1) {
    $last_word = array_pop($new_array[0]);
    array_unshift($new_array[1], $last_word);
}

$first_string = join(' ', $new_array[0]);
$second_string = join(' ', $new_array[1]);

$new_string = '<span>' . $first_string . '</span>' . ' <span>' . $second_string . '</span>';
echo htmlspecialchars($new_string);
```

Edit: Used ceil and added a condition in which if there's an odd number of words, move the last word from the first part to the second part

Comment: Thank you, but I actually want the second part to contain the additional word. This one also seems to duplicate the word, `sit`, and put it into the first part

Comment: @user13286 i just edited the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ceil()` to round up the result, that way the extra word will go to the second span if the result number of words is odd:

```
$per_part = max(ceil($count / 2), 1);
```

Comment: I thought that would work as well, but unfortunately it gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this earlier answer about how to split a string in half](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67281212/2943403), you can calculate half of the total number of words and round down.  Then use a regex pattern to match the two halves and wrap them in span tags.

Notice that my snippet is even punctuation safe and endeavours to loosely accommodate hyphenated words and contractions.  Some fringe cases will still cause trouble, but I don't know how your input data may vary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oW0Jm))

```
$text = "The Quick : Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy / Dog";
$wordCountInFirstHalf = intdiv(str_word_count($text), 2);
echo preg_replace(
         "~((?:[\w'-]+[^\w'-]*?){{$wordCountInFirstHalf}})(\s*)(.*)~",
         '<span>$1</span>$2<span>$3</span>',
         $text
     );
```

Output:

```
<span>The Quick : Brown Fox</span> <span>Jumped Over The Lazy / Dog</span>
```

---

<sub>I suppose it is responsible to declare that this snippet is not built to correctly handle a 1-word string.  In this scenario, you would be wise to write a condition to check if the word count is 1, then handle that as you desire instead of calling `preg_replace()`.</sub>